# Ethernet connection kept trying to connect but failing, more issues ensued

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

Alrighty. I'm brand new to Ubuntu and Linux, so bear with me here.

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 today, as I've been interested in linux and want to get into it, but I'm having a serious issue (again).

I plugged in my ethernet cable (WHICH IS WORKING AS THERE IS A BLINKING LIGHT ON BOTH THE ROUTER AND THE COMPUTER) and it began to connect, as shown by the little connection symbol on the top bar. It attempted to connect for a little while before saying that it failed/disconnected or whatever. It then began to do this over and over endlessly.

I then found a tutorial online to set a net mask, IP and stuff in my IPV4 tab of my network settings and set it to Manual rather than automatic. This seemed to work, as I had the symbol of two arrows and it said "connected" or something along those lines.I tried to use the internet (tried going on firefox and connecting to my website with ssh) but neither worked. The tutorial DID mention something about DNS keys or addresses, but I left that blank because I have no idea what to do with it. Could that be the issue?

Either way, I deleted that specific connection and tried again, but now it wont even TRY to connect. Any help?

EDIT: I filled in the DNS section with a DNS I found using the windows cmd, since the Linux terminal refused to give me one. The status is now back to the arrow symbol implying that it is connected, but the internet not actually working. [Here's an image of everything going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjej1.jpg)